# How to get value of key in dictionary after UITableViewCell is clicked in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dictionary

I am trying to set up a `UITableView` inside of a `UIViewController`. It works fine for me.

First of all, what i did:

**1)** I got response from server like this:

```
[{"email_id":"adas@faga.gs","id":66,"mobile_no":"1236547895","name":"asad","relation":"dsfs"},{"email_id":"raj@ghj.com","id":67,"mobile_no":"5632145412","name":"raj","relation":"xyz"},{"email_id":"surajsukale@gmail.com","id":68,"mobile_no":"8698819943","name":"suraj","relation":"self"}]
```

**2)** Display 4 values in all dictionaries in prototype cell successfully.

ie: `email_id`, `mobile_no`, `name`and `relation`.

**Note:** Here i get 5 parameters in response, but i display only 4.

Here is what i did for that:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [menuItems count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EmergencyContactCell";

    EmergencyContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.name.text = content[@"name"];
    cell.email.text = content[@"email_id"];
    cell.mobile.text =content[@"mobile_no"];
    cell.relation.text =content[@"relation"];

    return cell;
}
```

and it work perfectly for me.

**Now, What i want?**

When i clicked on any cell, i want to get particular id which is in that dictionary.
What should i do here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);

// What should i do here is my question ??
    }
```

Please anyone can solve my issue. help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like

```
NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSNumber *number = content["id"];
```

In you need a plain data type, use the appropriate property, for example:

```
int iNumber = number.intValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *id = content[@"id"];
 }
```

But i cannot understand why although you parsed the value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you still ask for the same processing in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 2):

Write below code to your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *id = content[@"id"];
```

You have not shown `id` in list but you can access it. Because it is in your dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

plz use this

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       int id = [[[menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"id"]intValue];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access your menuItems the same way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *yourItem = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```